# Correcting tables except page tables during page fault?

Tags: operating-system, paging, virtual-memory

I am a novice in an operating system and curious about the page fault.
I am reading Operating System Concetp(10th) and it say:

A handling page fault follow these sequence

```
1. Trap to the operating system
2. Save the user registers and process state
3. Determine that the interrupt was a page fault
4. Check that the page reference was legal and determine the location of the page on the disk
5. Issue a read from the disk to a free frame:
  a. Wait in a queue for this device until the read request is serviced
  b. Wait for the device seek and/or latency time
  c. Begin the transfer of the page to a free frame
6. While waiting, allocate the CPU to some other user
7. Receive an interrupt from the disk I/O subsystem (I/O completed)
8. Save the registers and process state for the other user
9. Determine that the interrupt was from the disk
10. Correct the page table and other tables to show that the page is now in memory
11. Wait for the CPU to be allocated to this process again
12. Restore the user registers, process state, and new page table, and then resume the interrupted instruction
```

I cannot imagine **other tables** in step 10 other than the page table.
Can you give me some examples?

Comment: I guess your book is to broad. I would refer to osdev.org for better info. I implemented paging in a minimal operating system I wrote. You could read the Intel developers manual as well. It is very specific and talks about all versions of their CPUs.

Answer (score 1):

Modern CPUs expect several page tables. For x86-64, the MMU (memory management unit) in the CPU takes the address stored in the CR3 register (stored there at boot by the OS). This address is the address of the first table (PML4). The PML4 table contains addresses of the second table and so on. The virtual address is split into 5 parts. The first 4 parts are the offsets in respective tables and the last part (12 bits) is the offset in the page in main memory. Today, only 48 bits of the 64 bits virtual addresses are used.

When you use virtual addressing the CPU will translate the virtual address using the MMU before putting the address on the address bus. It will basically cross each table taking one part of the virtual address at a time until it reaches the last table which is present in memory.

When a page fault occurs, a certain interrupt line is raised by the CPU. The interrupt number (of a page fault) is linked to a certain handler in the IDT by the OS at boot. The address of the IDT in RAM is stored in the LIDT register. The handler will do the steps mentioned in your example. It will correct all page tables and return.